# How to get the root domain to work properly?

Tags: domain-name-system

As far as I know, the top most domain is `.`.  So, shouldn't `ibm.com` be more appropriately refered to as `ibm.com.`?  Or rather, `ibm.com.` should always work with any application.

I went to Chrome browser and entered `ibm.com.` and it worked as I expected.  Same for `google.com.` and `www.apple.com.`.  However, for some other domains, eg `www.comcast.com.` and `a.azurewebsites.net.`, putting the period at the end results in a **400 error: The request hostname is invalid**.

So far, the examples that I found that will not work with the trailing period are from IIS sites. But I tested only a few example domain names.

What must be done where in order to make the trailing period work as expected?

Comment: Get those sites to use a grown-up web server.  Congratulations, looks like you've found yet another standard that MS didn't implement properly.  The process of adding a trailing dot to a domain name, to make the relationship to the DNS root explicit, is known as canonicalisation.

Comment: There was some discussion of this recently under http://serverfault.com/questions/682993/fully-qualified-domain-names-dhcp-dns-search-suffixes-and-trailing-dots

Comment: @PaulHaldane So it seems like this is a web server issue.  Thanks.

Comment: @MadHatter Yes, it seems like all the problem sites are Microsoft so far, including stackoverflow.com.  But is it an IIS problem?  If the binding is configured to `abc.com`, then rightfully IIS should not respond to `abc.com.`.

Comment: And that's your original observation: it doesn't.  Web servers bind to IP addresses, not hostnames; the requested hostname isn't transmitted by the client until the TCP connection is well-established, so it's too late for the server not to "pick up the phone", as it were.  All it can do if you request a hostname it can't serve is say *Requested hostname is invalid*, or equivalent - which is what IIS is doing, even though it *ought* to know that it *can* serve the requested hostname.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try this with a browser (the answer depends on the webservers configuration). To query DNS, use a DNS tool like "dig" (Domain Information Groper):

- `dig ibm.com.`
- `dig comcast.com.`
- `dig a.azurewebsites.net.`

and so on, and you will get what you are expecting.

Comment: Yes, but a major application of domain names is in browsers.

Answer (score -1):

There are two different protocols.

1: DNS. It gives the IP address of the remote side. Because of the structure (and of the protocol) of the domain name system, `sld.tld.` is just so a valid name, as `sld.tld` .

2: HTTP. If the browser connects to the webserver and gets a page, it says in his request not only the path part of the remote url, but also its hostname. Why is it so? Because millions of domain names could be reachable on the same IP address, and the server side hasn't any other option to fnd out, which hostname is you browser asking for.

If you extend the domain name with a `.`, it will be still a valid DNS request, and will get the same IP address as if you did without a tailing point.

But it the case of the http, it will be a completely different hostname. HTTP doesn't know anything about this DNS feature, although theoretically it would be possible to configure most webservers to handle such hostnames, too.

But they aren't. Nobody wants to see sites with these trailig edges. On the webserver side, it will be a request belonging to a hostname unknown for him.

What does it in this case, it depends on their sysadmin. Most webhosting providers only redirect this to their "pay now, pay now, it is important" page, but any other possibility could be set as well.